# Deleting elements in an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would i go about creating a set of buttons which when clicked deletes individual elements stored in an associative array? I've tried the splice element.. but it doesn't seem to work. I'm new to programming so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
bodyText = bodyText + '<input type="button" id="btnDeleteQuestion" 
value="Delete a question" onClick="questionBank.splice.(0,1) ">';
```

Comment: `splice()` is for numeric arrays, not associative arrays (objects).

Comment: There shouldn't be a `.` after `splice`.

Comment: What is the value of `questionBank`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associative arrays in JavaScript are plain old objects with key/value pairs. Use the `delete` operator to delete a key.

```js
var myObject = {
  key1:"key1Value",
  key2:"key2Value",
  key3:"key3Value",  
  key4:"key4Value"  
};

console.log(myObject);

document.getElementById("btnDeleteQuestion").addEventListener("click", function(){
  delete myObject["key4"];
  console.log(myObject);  
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnDeleteQuestion" value="Delete a question">
```